# Send generated zip file with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, attachment, zip

I'm using the express module in a NodeJS server to generate a zip file. The express server is responding to many requests, so I know that is set up correctly, but I'm having trouble generating a zip file and sending that back as a downloadable.

I don't want to save the file and then tell Express to send that file as a download, I just want to send the zip file as data from memory. Here is what I have so far.

```
function buildZipFile(data, filename) {
    var zip = new require('node-zip')();
    zip.file(filename, data, { base64: false });
    return zip.generate();
}

var data = buildZipFile('hello world', 'hello.txt');
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/zip')
res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=file.zip');
res.set('Content-Length', data.length);
res.end(data, 'binary');
return;
```

The file will return, but neither windows unzip or 7zip are able to open the archive, as if it is corrupt. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pass your options to `zip.generate` not `zip.file`. This creates a zip archive I can properly inspect/unzip via `zipinfo`/`unzip`.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var Zip = require('node-zip');
var zip = new Zip;
zip.file('hello.txt', 'Hello, World!');
var options = {base64: false, compression:'DEFLATE'};
fs.writeFile('test1.zip', zip.generate(options), 'binary', function (error) {
  console.log('wrote test1.zip', error);
});
```

Comment: Can I do this without saving to hdd?

Comment: Yes, `zip.generate` gives you in-memory data. From there you can decide to stream it as an HTTP response body or wherever else you like.

Comment: Note 2018: `node-zip` seems not active anymore and is an extremely thin wrapper around `JSZip`. Just use JSZip directly, since it's more active.